# How to enable folder sharing using netsh?

Tags: windows, firewall, netsh

I'm trying to enable folder sharing for all.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes
```

Seems to work for File and Printer but

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Public folder sharing" new enable=Yes
```

doesn't work (>>No rules match the specified criteria)

Comment: I don't see a rule named "Public folder sharing".

Comment: Exactly I'm not sure what's the name of the group for it too. But you can still find such a rule in Control Panel -> Advanced Sharing settings

Comment: The command 'netsh advfirewall' only manages firewall settings, it has nothing to do with actually sharing folders.

Comment: @FoxyZ did you ever find a definitive answer to your question? I need to do the same "enable" for public folder sharing (settings usually set in Network & Sharing > Advanced Sharing settings > Under All networks > Check "Turn on sharing..." I'm doing it for several Azure Cloud PCs for a third-party software and want to do it without touching each device (Using endpoint manager to deploy script if possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I haven’t understood your question correctly, but with

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes
```

you configure firewall for SMB protocol(SMB is used for File/Folder sharing). So you should be able to create a share with:

```
net share sharename=folderpath /grant:username,permissions
```

If you require the Network Discovery:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=Yes
```